# JSF selectOneRadio, rendering only certain items

Tags: jsf-2, radio-button

Is there any possibility rendering just certain items (based on their value) of radio buttons in jsf

```
 e.g this below: (but this approach doesn't work)

 <h:selectOneRadio value="#{user.favColor3}">
        <f:selectItems rendered="c.colorValue eq 'red'" .... var="c"
 </h:selectOneRadio>
```

So, I want to iterate over the items, and showing only the red item.

Thanks in advance.

Cs

Comment: This doesn't cause `selectItems` doesn't have any rendered attribute

Comment: Ok, but then how can it be solved this kind of problem ? (skipping item from the list in the jsf part)